# hide/show control in mvc4 cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I have two **Dropdownlist** as follows

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ddl_SearchBy", new List<SelectListItem> 
     { 
       new SelectListItem{Text="PA Number",Value="PA"},
       new SelectListItem{Text="Customer Code" ,Value="CustCode"},
       new SelectListItem{Text="Customer Name" ,Value="CustName"},
       new SelectListItem{Text="Order Type" ,Value="OrderType"},
       new SelectListItem{Text="Discount Type" ,Value="DiscType"},
       new SelectListItem{Text="EIC", Value="EIC"},
       new SelectListItem{Text="Status", Value="status"}
      }, "-Select Criteria-", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddl_SearchBy" }                            

@Html.DropDownList("ddl_OrderType", Model.lstOrderType, "-Select Order Type-", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlOrderType"})    
@Html.DropDownList("ddl_Status", Model.lstStatus, "-Select Status-", new { @class = "form-control", @style = "display:none", @id = "ddl_Status" })
```

In Jquery I have done something like this

```
$('#ddl_SearchBy').change(function () {              
    if ($('#ddl_SearchBy').val() == 'status') {
        $("#ddlDiscountType").hide();
        $("#ddlStatus").show();
    }
});
```

but when i changed event ddlstatus not shown

Comment: Where is ddl_SearchBy id in your cshtml file?

Comment: I think your id's are not matching

Answer (score 0):

You can change visibility option by putting them in the DIV and make DIV hide and show depends on your requirement.

Please try [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You can do following two changes,

1). In CSHTML File

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddl_Status", Model.lstStatus, "-Select Status-", new { @class = "form-control", @style = "display:none", @id = "ddl_Status" })
```

change id to "ddlStatus", like follows,

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddl_Status", Model.lstStatus, "-Select Status-", new { @class = "form-control", @style = "display:none", @id = "ddlStatus" })
```

2). in JS File

```
$('#ddl_SearchBy').change(function () {


    if ($('#ddl_SearchBy').val() == 'status') {
        $("#ddlDiscountType").hide();
        $("#ddl_Status").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your function with $(document).ready(function(){ });